# Change TableAttribute in runtime for Dapper

Tags: c#, reflection, data-annotations, dapper, custom-attributes

I use **Dapper** and **TableAttribute**:

```
using Dapper.Contrib.Extensions;

namespace MyCompany.Entities
{
    [Table(Config.TABLE_ARCHIVO_CLIENTE)] 
    public partial class ArchivoCliente
    {
```

Working

```
  public const string TABLE_ARCHIVO_CLIENTE = "Archivo_Cliente";
```

Not working if not `const string`. I try use a `static property` for use `appSettings`:

```
  public static string TABLE_ARCHIVO_CLIENTE
  {
       get
       {
           return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get(KeyTable);
       }
  }
```

Any suggestions for using **AppSettings** ?

Answer (score 1):

Attribute parameters require constants.

Checking the Dapper.Contrib code, it appears *very unusually* to access the attribute **by name**. If it was **by type**, you could do something like:

```
class ConfigTableAttribute : TableAttribute {
    public ConfigTableAttribute(string configSetting)
         : base(LookupTableNameFromConfig(configSetting));

    private static string LookupTableNameFromConfig(string configSetting)
    {
        // TODO: your code here
    }
}
```

and annotate your code with:

```
[ConfigTable(nameof(Config.TABLE_ARCHIVO_CLIENTE))]
class Foo {}
```

It would then be your job to implement the TODO which would fetch the actual value via reflection or an indexer, etc. In the code shown, the input `configSetting` would be `TABLE_ARCHIVO_CLIENTE`.

---

However, since it accesses it by *name* and `dynamic`, all you actually need is something *called* `TableAttribute` that *has* a `Name`. You could do the same thing as above, but in a different namespace:

```
namespace MyEvilness {
    class TableAttribute : Attribute {
        public TableAttribute(string configSetting) {
             Name = LookupTableNameFromConfig(configSetting);
        }
        // etc as before
    }
}
```

and use:

```
[MyEvilness.Table(nameof(Config.TABLE_ARCHIVO_CLIENTE))]
class Foo {}
```

---

Word of caution; I consider the current implementation to be a bug! I understand *why* it is done that way (i.e. so it works with EF), but I'm tempted to make it work for *either* approach.

Comment: Would you elaborate on how to ensure sql injection safety on the tablenames acquired from configuration file, or point me in direction of it?

Comment: @nae step 1: have a list of known table names; step 2: check against that list

Answer (score 0):

I've written a small [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper.Contrib.Extensions.Tablename) to overcome this issue. It assigns the value as tablename if the key matches to [`FullName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.fullname?view=netcore-3.1), in the configuration file. With *some* effort spend to avoid sql injection.

One can add it like dependency injection

```
// Startup.cs or Program.cs
// ...
services.ReadTablenamesFromConfig(configuration.GetSection("MySectionName"));
// ...
```

with configuration:

```
// appsettings.json
...
  "MySectionName": {
    "TableNames": {
      "Demo.Sale": "sale_2020"
    }
  },
...
```

For the model:

```
// Sale.cs
namespace Demo
{
    //[Table("sale_2020")]
    public class Sale
    {
        public string Product { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }
}
```

See a *better* example [here](https://github.com/bali-ibrahim/Dapper.Contrib.Extensions.Tablename).

---

As for the time being, the implementation is as follows:

```
// TablenameExtensions.cs
using Dapper.Contrib.Extensions;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System;

namespace Dapper.Contrib.Extensions.Tablename
{
    public static class TablenameExtensions
    {
        private static TablenameConfig _config;
        public static IServiceCollection ReadTablenamesFromConfig(this IServiceCollection services, IConfigurationSection configSection)
        {
            services.Configure<TablenameConfig>(configSection);
            _config = configSection.Get<TablenameConfig>();
            SqlMapperExtensions.TableNameMapper = TableName;
            return services;
        }

        private static string TableName(Type type) => _config.TableNames[type.FullName].Replace("`", "");
        public static string TableName<T>() => TableName(typeof(T));
    }
}
```

where:

```
// TablenameConfig.cs
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Dapper.Contrib.Extensions.Tablename
{
    internal class TablenameConfig
    {
        public IDictionary<string, string> TableNames { get; set; }
    }
}
```